# Testing a file upload in phoenix/elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to test controller that expects a file upload using the phoenix framework. I followed the guide at the phoenix guides (http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/file-uploads)  and it works in the browser, but i'm having trouble writing a test for it. Here's what i did:

```ex
test "POST photo" do 
  { :ok, raw_file } = File.read "1528_27.jpg"
  conn() |> post("/api/v1/originals", %{ :image => raw_file })
  # do some assertions
end
```

The problem is, in the controller, my file never ends up as a `%Plug.Upload` struct, but as binary. So when testing, my params in the controller look like:

```ex
params: %{"image" => <<255, 216, 255, 225, 18, 180, 69, 120, 105, 102, 0, 0, 73, 73, 42, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 15, 1, 2, 0, 26, 0, 0, 0, 134, 0, 0, 0, 16, 1, 2, 0, 10, 0, ...>>},
```

and my controller blows up when trying to access `params["image"].path`. This works when uploading from the browser though, because then, i have the expected Upload struct in my params:

```ex
params: %{
  "image" => %Plug.Upload{
    content_type: "image/jpeg",
    filename: "1528_27.jpg",
    path: "/var/folders/98/40k7dt2d2sxf6xnkc_627lqc0000gp/T//plug-1448/multipart-280987-612081-2"
  }
},
```

How can i `post` a file from a test, so i get a `%Plug.Upload` struct, and not just binary?

Comment: I think one of these is the current location of the documentation @screnig linked to in the question: https://phoenixframework.readme.io/docs/file-uploads https://www.phoenixframework.org/blog/file-uploads

Comment: In case anybody want to have simple project to do upload file in Phoenix https://www.yodiw.com/simple-upload-file-local-phoenix-elixir/

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Put a file in your test directory somewhere (maybe `test/fixtures`) then use the [Plug.Upload](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Upload.html) struct:

```
upload = %Plug.Upload{path: "test/fixtures/example.png", filename: "example.png"}
conn() |> post("/api/v1/originals", %{ :image => upload })
```

Comment: Is there any way to test this without physically reading from a fixture file on the disk? I prefer my tests to run in memory if at all possible

Comment: @Gazler how to test multiple uploads? `Plug.Upload` only supports one file at a time

Comment: @Tanweer Presumably you'd be using something like `<input type="file" name="image[]" multiple>`. In this case, you'd pass a list in post. `post("/api/v1/originals", %{ :image => [%Plug.Upload{}, %Plug.Upload{}] })`

Comment: Note that one might also want to specify the `content-type` field in the `%Plug.Upload` struct, which is normally present in files uploaded via the user interface.

Comment: @pmarreck The `path` in the application context points a file in the tmp directory which must be copied to target directory. So if you mock the code that access the file then you dont need the file saved on your disk any more.